# How to use Doctrine 2 FileSystemCache width Zend 2

Tags: php, zend-framework, doctrine-orm

I'm currently working on a Zend 2 project and want to use Doctrines FilesystemCache.

In my module.config.php i have the following lines:

```
'doctrine'           => array(
    'driver' => array(
        __NAMESPACE__ . '_driver'    => array(
            'class'  => 'Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\AnnotationDriver',
            'cache' => array(
                'filesystem' => array(
                    'class' => '\Doctrine\Common\Cache\FilesystemCache',
                    'directory' => __DIR__ . '/../data/cache/' . __NAMESPACE,
                )
            )
            'paths'  => array(__DIR__ . '/../src/' . __NAMESPACE__ . '  /Entity')
        ),
        'orm_default'                => array(

            'drivers' => array(
                __NAMESPACE__ . '\Entity' => __NAMESPACE__ .    '_driver'
            )
        )
    ),
```

With the above config my entities are not cached, and it gives me the following notice:

Array to string conversion in /webroot/vendor/doctrine/doctrine-module/src/DoctrineModule/Options/Driver.php on line 90

When i change my config to just a string:

```
'cache' => 'filesystem'
```

i see the FilesystemCache tries to cache my entities to a default location (?) but fails with warnings like:

Warning: file_put_contents(/var/www/webroot/data/DoctrineModule/cache/e4165aec32e5/87e827598d3b/bdef3af2/[File\Entity\File$name@[Annot]][1].doctrinecache.data): failed to open stream: Invalid argument in /var/www/webroot/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Cache/FilesystemCache.php on line 111

Answer (score 0):

Probably you shoul use `__NAMESPACE__` constant rather than `__NAMESPACE`

There is no such directory